# Android - Drawing a maze to canvas with smooth character movement

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I am currently creating a Tile based game which essentially draws a maze using 2 sets of booleans arrays to determine where each wall needs to be drawn.

I have this all working as it should, with only a 5 x 5 section of the maze being drawn (overall maze size is 30 x 30). However, the issue I am having is when I move the character, the whole screen jumps, this is due to the fact that the next section of the maze is being drawn, to maintain the 5 x 5 aspect ratio. I have tried various different things to try to get this run smoothly however simply cannot seem to be able to do this.

Can somebody advise or direct me to some links / examples so that I can get the maze and character movements all to happen smoothly. Below is some basic code as to the main for loop that currently draws the maze and the 2 boolean arrays that it references in order to draw the walls.

```
// THE CODE TO DRAW THE MAZE AND ITS WALLS
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        float x = j * totalCellWidth;
        float y = i * totalCellHeight;

        if(currentY != 0)
            indexY = i + currentY - 1;
        else
            indexY = i + currentY;

        if(currentX != 0)
            indexX = j + currentX - 1;
        else
            indexX = j + currentX;

         // Draw Verticle line (y axis)
        if (indexY < vLength && indexX < vLines[indexY].length && vLines[indexY][indexX])
        {
            RectOuterBackground.set((int)x + (int)cellWidth, (int)y, (int)x + (int)cellWidth + 15,  (int)y + (int)cellHeight + 15);
            canvas.drawBitmap(walls, null, RectOuterBackground, null);
        }
        // Draws Horizontal lines (x axis)
        if (indexY < hLength && indexX < hLines[indexY].length && hLines[indexY][indexX])
        {
            RectOuterBackground.set((int)x, (int)y + (int)cellHeight,(int)x + (int)cellWidth + 15,(int)y + (int)cellHeight + 15);
            canvas.drawBitmap(walls, null, RectOuterBackground, null);
        }
    }
}

// THE 2 BOOLEAN ARRAYS THE FORLOOP REFERENCES
boolean[][] vLines = new boolean[][]{
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,false,false,false,true ,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,false,false,true ,false,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,false,false,true ,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,true ,false,false,false,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,false,false,false,true ,true ,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,false,false,true ,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,false,false,true ,false,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true }
 };
boolean[][] hLines = new boolean[][]{
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,false,true ,true ,false,false,true ,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,false,true ,true ,false,true ,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,false,true ,true ,false,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,false,true ,false,true ,true ,false,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,true ,true ,true ,false,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,false,false,true ,false,false,true ,false,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,false,true ,false,false,false,true ,false,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true },
    {true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true ,true }
};
```

I am willing to completly re-write that section of code if I can get it to draw smoothly, however having tried several different varations cannot get it smooth, I always have the jump.

I was trying to also get it to work with canvas translate, by drawing the whoel maze out, then scale it so that only 5 x 5 was displayed then simply moving the scaled section along using translate, whilst keeping the character in the center of the screen, there giving a smooth movement. However, I just could not get the translate to move along smoothly.

Comment: Are you willing to use a third-party game engine(library), or do you want to solve this problem using only Android library?

Comment: I have no problem using a 3rd party library, as long as it fits into my current layout, what do you have in mind?

Comment: Show us your game loop class/method. Do you run on main thread or your own thread?

Comment: I run my own thread, essentially i just call invalidate() when the character moves, the characters position is tracked and then the relevant sections of the maze are drawn referencing the boolean arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a full Maze class. It draws the view to coordinates viewX and viewY which can be moved either smoothly (as in Boudjnah's answer) or with multiplies of the cell dimensions.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class Maze {
    private RectF drawRect = new RectF();

    private Bitmap[] bitmaps;
    private int[][] tileType;

    private float screenWidth, screenHeight;

    /**
     * Initialize a new maze.
     * @param wallBitmap The desired bitmaps for the floors and walls
     * @param isWall The wall data array. Each true value in the array represents a wall and each false represents a gap
     * @param xCellCountOnScreen How many cells are visible on the screen on the x axis
     * @param yCellCountOnScreen How many cells are visible on the screen on the y axis
     * @param screenWidth The screen width
     * @param screenHeight The screen height
     */
    public Maze(Bitmap[] bitmaps, int[][] tileType, float xCellCountOnScreen, float yCellCountOnScreen, float screenWidth, float screenHeight){
        this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
        this.tileType = tileType;

        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight;

        drawRect.set(0, 0, screenWidth / xCellCountOnScreen, screenHeight / yCellCountOnScreen);
    }

    /**
     * Get the type of the cell. x and y values are not coordinates!
     * @param x The x index of the cell
     * @param y The y index of the cell
     * @return The cell type
     */
    public int getType(int x, int y){
        if(y < tileType.length && x < tileType[y].length) return tileType[y][x];
        return 0;
    }

    public float getCellWidth(){ return drawRect.width(); }
    public float getCellHeight(){ return drawRect.height(); }

    /**
     * Draws the maze. View coordinates should have positive values.
     * @param canvas Canvas for the drawing
     * @param viewX The x coordinate of the view
     * @param viewY The y coordinate of the view
     */
    public void drawMaze(Canvas canvas, float viewX, float viewY){
        int tileX = 0;
        int tileY = 0;
        float xCoord = -viewX;
        float yCoord = -viewY;

        while(tileY < tileType.length && yCoord <= screenHeight){
            // Begin drawing a new column
            tileX = 0;
            xCoord = -viewX;

            while(tileX < tileType[tileY].length && xCoord <= screenWidth){
                // Check if the tile is not null
                if(bitmaps[tileType[tileY][tileX]] != null){

                    // This tile is not null, so check if it has to be drawn
                    if(xCoord + drawRect.width() >= 0 && yCoord + drawRect.height() >= 0){

                        // The tile actually visible to the user, so draw it
                        drawRect.offsetTo(xCoord, yCoord); // Move the rectangle to the coordinates
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmaps[tileType[tileY][tileX]], null, drawRect, null);
                    }
                }

                // Move to the next tile on the X axis
                tileX++;
                xCoord += drawRect.width();
            }

            // Move to the next tile on the Y axis
            tileY++;
            yCoord += drawRect.height();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this class, first initialize it in your onCreate function like this

```
// 0 == floor, 1 == wall, 2 == different looking wall
int[][] maze = {
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
        {1, 1, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};

Bitmap[] bitmaps = {
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floor),
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.firstwall)
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.secondwall)
};

// Chance the 480 and 320 to match the screen size of your device
maze = new Maze(bitmaps, maze, 5, 5, 480, 320);
```

And then draw it in your onDraw or similar function like this

```
maze.draw(canvas, viewX, viewY);
```

The getType(int x, int y), getCellWidth() and getCellHeight() functions should help you to implement any interactions with the maze. You can also add your own functions to the class. You can also modify this class to note any starting and ending tiles. I won't make your whole game for you :)

If you set your character to coordinates (x, y) and draw it to coordinates (x - viewX, y - viewY) you can have a fixed position for it relative to the maze wherever the view is.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm a noob to java and android development and cannot quite work out how to implement your code into mine, whilst keeping the boolean array structure to draw the maze and move it smoothly. I have tried drawing the entire maze, and scaling, which works fine, however cannot get it to move smoothly as it always reDraws the maze giving the jumping movemenet.

Comment: I edited my answer with a full Maze class code. Give it the wall Bitmap, a boolean array of the level layout (true = wall, false = no wall), the desired amount of cells on the screen (in your case 5) and the screen dimensions (can be estimated for testing purposes). This code assumes that you only want to draw the walls. Please tell me if you want this class to draw the floors too or if you have many types of walls that you want to draw.

Comment: To move your maze smoothly, add small float values to the viewX and viewY values. For example by repeating viewX += 0.1f; every time you have drawn your maze, your view will begin moving to the right, which means your maze is moving to the left. If you move both your character and view coordinates to the right by the same amount, your character will stay in the same position on the screen and only the maze will move.

Comment: To be honest, I don't get where you need two arrays for the wall placements. It made your code really confusing to read and I still don't quite get it. This code uses only one array, which has two dimensions.

Comment: I will try to implement this tomorrow morning, in terms of the walls and ground, yes I would ideally need to put a floor in and the walls may change a little however I will manually amend bitmap being displayed elsewhere.

Comment: I tried using Tiled, however I could not work out how to implement the .tmx file without having to completely re-write my entire app.

Comment: 1 quick follow up question, does this mean I can remove all the code from within my onDraw? Also, I have implemented your Maze class into my GameView, how would I go about call it correctly? As it is currerntly called from my Game.class, which fetches certin data such as starting postion, end position, maze details from my own Maze.class? Thanks

Comment: I added support for many different tiles and also added an example how to use the class. Please read through my modified answer. This code totally replaces your other maze drawing and handling code, but it ONLY draws the maze. You have to modify the class to include character interactions and I suggest you to combine this class with your own Maze class. Just to clarify, this class doesn't have anything to do with Tiled as I originally wrote it to handle randomly generated maps.

Comment: Thanks for this, its quite a big change and there is a lot of additional things that happends within my GameView class, therefore it will take me a while to implement it all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44406/discussion-between-landl-partners-and-finnboy11)

Answer (score 3):

Use [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) or another Android game engine like [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) (I haven't used this one). Developing a game using only Android library is really hard and error-prone (you have to write a lot of boilerplate code which is already done for you in the game engines). LibGDX can simplify your task in many ways:

- It's graphics API is implemented in OenGL (you wan't have problems with performance in a simple 2D game like yours)
- It has a nice support for 2D tile based games ( https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Tiles)
- It is a cross-platform engine. The supported platforms are iOS, BlackBerry, Desktop(Windows, Linux and Mac) and HTML 5.

Comment: This would be useful, however would require me to re-write my whole game which is too time consuming, is there another way my issue can be resolved?

Comment: @LandLPartners not the entire game, only the rendering part.

Comment: Ok makes sense, however a few follow up questions you may already know the answer to, firstly can this still be coded in Java and can i use the same for loop structure against 2 sets of booleans arrays as shown in my code to create the mazes? Also, can this be easily implemented into Eclipse?

Comment: @LandLPartners LibGDX is a Java library. You can use it to write Java code that will work on all the platforms mentioned in my answer. You can use it in Eclipse. It is just a library(a couple of jar files)! I think [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki) wiki contains the answers to all of your questions. Drawing the maze with LibGDX will be much easier using tile maps.

Comment: OK I will have a read of all the documentation and give it a go over the next few days.

Comment: I am trying to use a .tmx file which I have created using Tiled, however it looks like I would need to re-write my whole app, which does not work for me. I need to simply replace the onDraw section only, do you know any other way I can resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

One approach you might consider is keeping the character in the center of the screen at all times. Rather than moving your character, only move the offset on the maze. This method is common in many old (and possibly new) role playing games.

Comment: Hi, I have actually tried that and come to the conclusion that the character in the center is a must. However I cannot seem to get the maze to draw smoothly, essentially pixel by pixel as the user moves. The user position moves from one tile to the next. Could you please supply some sample code?

Comment: Here's one approach, but I'll leave the actual coding to you or to another user: rather than working on the 5 x 5 grid, work on a 7 x 7 grid. After moving the character smoothly to the next tile by sliding the canvas with all tiles, update all 7 tiles to the new offset. Of course, you still have to take into account the edges, which would require the user to leave the center of the screen.

Comment: Yes that was the kind of thing I was trying to implement, however was struggling to code it. Might start fresh and give it another go tonight.

Comment: Hi, I have tried implementing this, however cannot get it to work. I a noob to Java and Android developement and cannot work out how to get it to draw smoothly when i invalidate(), is there same sample code you could point me towards?

Comment: Try this tutorial and the other tutorials on that site, they seem wonderful for your needs:

http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/

Answer (score 0):

What about drawing the whole maze bitmap in an OpenGL ES - View and adjusting the viewport / camera position? This would give you the opportunity of nice effects when moving through the maze and is absolutly smooth.

Comment: I had considered that, however this would require me to write my whole game, which is complete minus the moving the character smoothly.

Comment: Not really . You still would only  have  to write a 5x5area + home reasonable + for  there smooth  navigation , say a maze of 15x15, so that every maze near to the area displayed is already there for smooth navigation . You would Not have to redraw areas You have drawn already since  you are using a bitmap .